# Creating square class extending rectangle class

Tags: java

I was tasked with creating a Square class that extends the Rectangle class which overrides the methods so that the Square maintains its "squareness" (all sides are equal). I have completed the methods for add(int, int) and add(rectangle) but am struggling with overriding the grow(int, int) method. That method needs to Override the grow(int, int) method such that the Square grows at least that much and still maintains its squareness. How can I fix that method so that It overrides the Rectangle classes method and works correctly?
Here is my code:

```
public class Square extends Rectangle{
    
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int s;
    
    public Square(int x, int y, int s) {
        super(x,y,s, s);
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.s=s;
}

    @Override
    public void add(int one, int two) {
        
        super.add(one, two);
        super.add(this.getX() +this.getHeight() , this.getY() + this.getWidth() );
        
        
        }
    
    @Override
    public void add(Rectangle rec) {
        super.add(rec);
        super.add(this.getX() +this.getHeight() , this.getY() + this.getWidth() );
    }

    @Override
    public void grow(int one, int two) {
        
        super.grow(one,two);
        this.add(one,two);
    
}}
```

Comment: Can you post implementation of Rectangle too?

Comment: The rectangle is the Java API Rectangle class :

Comment: public void grow(int h,
        int v)
Resizes the Rectangle both horizontally and vertically.
This method modifies the Rectangle so that it is h units larger on both the left and right side, and v units larger at both the top and bottom.

The new Rectangle has (x - h, y - v) as its upper-left corner, width of (width + 2h), and a height of (height + 2v).

If negative values are supplied for h and v, the size of the Rectangle decreases accordingly."

Comment: If negative values are supplied for h and v, the size of the Rectangle decreases accordingly. The grow method will check for integer overflow and underflow, but does not check whether the resulting values of width and height grow from negative to non-negative or shrink from non-negative to negative.

Parameters:
h - the horizontal expansion
v - the vertical expansion